# Hibernate criteria for OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, many-to-one, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-onetomany

I have a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship between two objects like:

```
public class Company {
    private Long compid;
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Employee> employees;
}

public class Employee {
    private Long empid;
    private String fstName;
    private String lstName;
    private String sal;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "compid", nullable = true)
    private Company company;
}
```

I want to get the employees who have `company.companyName like xxxx%`. I tried something like:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.createAlias("company", "company");
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("company.companyName ", "xxxx%"));
return criteria.list();
```

But i get the error:

```
could not resolve property: company.companyName of: Employee
```

Where is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of problem, it is a stupid error on my part, in my original code I put compny.companyName, I forgot an "a" in company, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `criteria.createCriteria` instead of `criteria.createAlias`

Answer (score 1):

You have added a space like `"company.companyName "` in 3rd line of criteria. Is it typo? If not then it is the cause of the problem.